# How can I show the integer in listview?

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, integer, android-arrayadapter

I want to show the for loop numbers on the listview, but it doesn't work.
[App's Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd84E.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView marksixlist;
    private Button mRandombtn, mCleanbtn;
    private TextView mText;
    private ArrayList<Integer> marksixnum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        marksixlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        mRandombtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randombtn);
        mCleanbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cleanbtn);
        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.items);

        mRandombtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                    int random = (int) (Math.random()* 49+1);
                        marksixnum.add(random);
                        Collections.shuffle(marksixnum);
                }
            }
        });

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.listitempage, marksixnum);
        marksixlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        Log.d("aaa", "The markssix is - " + marksixnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, please check my solution. Please accept the answer or vote up if it's acceptable.

Comment: please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you generate the random numbers and shuffle them then at the end of for loop add the `arrayAdapter` to the listview `marksixlist` again and it will work as a charm.

I have additionally cleared the ArrayList `marksixnum` before generating random numbers so that your list doesn't keep on growing.

Its optional, if you need last click elements then delete `marksixnum.clear()`

```
mRandombtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do this if you do not want
        // numbers from last click
        marksixnum.clear();
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random()* 49+1);
            marksixnum.add(random);
            Collections.shuffle(marksixnum);
        }
        // add arrayAdapter to listview
        marksixlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
});
```